# Is G-d chasing out the Cananite nations or does B'nai Yisra'el have to do this?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, mishpatim, masei

There appears to be a conflict of ideas regarding who should rid the land of Cana'an from its inhabitants:

Exodus 23:28-29 (Sefaria):

> וְשָׁלַחְתִּ֥י אֶת־הַצִּרְעָ֖ה לְפָנֶ֑יךָ וְגֵרְשָׁ֗ה אֶת־הַחִוִּ֧י
>   אֶת־הַֽכְּנַעֲנִ֛י וְאֶת־הַחִתִּ֖י מִלְּפָנֶֽיךָ׃ לֹ֧א אֲגָרְשֶׁ֛נּוּ
>   מִפָּנֶ֖יךָ בְּשָׁנָ֣ה אֶחָ֑ת פֶּן־תִּהְיֶ֤ה הָאָ֙רֶץ֙ שְׁמָמָ֔ה
>   וְרַבָּ֥ה עָלֶ֖יךָ חַיַּ֥ת הַשָּׂדֶֽה׃
>
> And I will send the hornet before thee, which shall drive out the
>   Hivite, the Canaanite, and the Hittite, from before thee. I will not
>   drive them out from before thee in one year, lest the land become
>   desolate, and the beasts of the field multiply against thee.

The above verse seems to imply that G-d will do the work. But,

Numbers 33:53:

> וְהוֹרַשְׁתֶּ֥ם אֶת־הָאָ֖רֶץ וִֽישַׁבְתֶּם־בָּ֑הּ כִּ֥י לָכֶ֛ם
>   נָתַ֥תִּי אֶת־הָאָ֖רֶץ לָרֶ֥שֶׁת אֹתָֽהּ׃
>
> And ye shall drive out the inhabitants of the land, and dwell therein;
>   for unto you have I given the land to possess it.

Seems to imply that the people have to do the work.

Which is it? Is it a bit of both? If so, who does which part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only the "חוי, כנעני, חתי" nations are mentioned in the first verse, and indeed *Bnei Israel* did not have to fight them (they left on their own). But there were other nations there (פרזי, יבוסי, etc.), most of whom they had to fight (And were commanded to do so) [[Malbim]](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40081&st=&pgnum=440).

Rashi (there, one page before) also differentiates between the specific nations mentioned in the first verse, as opposed to others.